# In nodejs how to have single instance of module having constructor with different parameters?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am getting two instances of a module when I am using the module with two different parameters. How to make it a single instance?

```js
// module.js

module.exports = function(declared){
 var count = {
  total : 0
 }
 var definedVariable = declared;
 function increment(){
  count.total++;
  return {
   defined : definedVariable,
   count : count.total
  }
 }
 return {
  increment : increment
 }
}
```

```js
// app.js

var express = require('express');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');

var mod1 = require('./module.js')();
var mod2 = require('./module.js')('defined now');

app = express();
app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(bodyparser.json());
app.route('/').get(function(req, res, next) {
    var cnt1 = mod1.increment();
    res.json(cnt1);
});
app.route('/defined').get(function(req,res,next){ 
 var cnt2 = mod2.increment();
    res.json(cnt2);
});
app.listen(8000, function(){
 console.log('listening 8000');
})
```

When I run http://localhost:8000 and http://localhost:8000/defined, I am getting different counts and different instances. How to let them point to the single instance?

Comment: @unobf I disagree. The question was clearly illustrated and relevant code was shared. Maybe it could have been rephrased slighty, but overall the question was answerable on first glance. Just because the poster may not grasp the concepts of scope and closures does not make his question bad. Telling people to "go away and learn something" is not constructive.

Answer (score 2):

Update your `module.js` to declare `count` outside of the exported function

```
// module.js
var count = {
    total : 0
}
module.exports = function(declared){
    var definedVariable = declared;
    function increment(){
        count.total++;
        return {
            defined : definedVariable,
            count : count.total
        }
    }
    return {
        increment : increment
    }
}
```

When `count` is inside the function body, it gets redeclared every time to you invoke the function from outside the module.

Answer (score 0):

Module.js is a singleton. But you aren't treating it as such. You need to create your variable inside the module, and then export your method to be used and increment the count and set the definedVariable when used as a closure.

```
// module.js
var count = {
        total : 0
    },
    definedVariable = declared;

module.exports = function(declared){
    function increment(){
        count.total++;
        return {
            defined : definedVariable,
            count : count.total
        }
    }
    return {
        increment : increment()
    }
}
```

Now in your server

```
//server.js

var mod = require('./module.js');

var mod1 = mod();
var mod2 = mod('defined now');
```